# what is the syntax of the HttpResponseMessage in framework 3.5?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Now current i am consuming others people project which is build under framework 4.0, however now i meet a syntax error which is HttpResponseMessage is not defined when post the code in the framework 3.5. May i ask what is the syntax of this?

HttpResponseMessage

i tried to pull out all the function in the library ended up only got httpResponse and HttpResponseHeader. In fact , if i using the httpResponse , more error they gave me.

Answer (score 0):

HttpResponseHeader only support on the system.net.http 4.0 above, with the framework 3.5 it is not allow.